# Two ethernet ports, same IP as device connected to other ethernet port

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have a small Device with two ethernet ports (NICs) running Ubuntu 16.04.
The first ethernetport has a static IP address (for example `10.0.0.2`)
The second ethernetport has static IP address (for example `10.0.0.3`) but is connected to a printer with the same IP address as the first ethernetport of my device (it has IP `10.0.0.2` in our example).
As expected, the printer cannot communicate because there is a duplicate IP address on the network. My Linux Device does not know whether to send information to its own NIC or two the printer.

My question is:
Can I control the network communication based on the devicename? Or is there any other way to solve this without having to change the IP addresses of Port 1 or the Printer?

Comment: Why is changing the IP a problem?

Comment: I want to put my Linux Device between a network and a printer so that other devices in the network print to my Linux Device instead of the printer. I want to modify the printjobs on the Linux Device before sending it to the printer. I am not allowed to change anything in the network (for example the IP of the printer) and if I change the IP of my Linux Device, other computers cannot print (raw by port 9100) to my Device anymore unless I reconfigure the printer on the other devices in the network.

Comment: Unless you change the IP of the printer, you won't be putting your device `in between`, you are putting it in parallel and I think it's going to be way more complex. I don't know how to help in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

No. You will have to move the printer on the network if you don't want to make it unnecessarily complicated for yourself.

To do what you want - correctly put your 'small device' between the printer and the network - you should connect to the main network on NIC 1, and connect NIC 2 to the printer alone. The printer and  NIC 2 should be on another IP range so that devices on the main network cannot connect directly to the printer. For example, with the printer connected only to NIC 2:

- NIC 1: 10.0.0.3
- NIC 2: 192.168.1.100
- Printer: 192.168.1.101 (mask /24, gateway NIC 2's IP)

From there, you can have a program listen on NIC 1, modify the print job, then send it to the printer over NIC 2. Having NIC 2 on a different subnet has the added convenience of making the system automatically choose NIC 2 to connect to the printer.